# Difference between jmeter response time and what i see on log file

Tags: java, performance, rest, jmeter

I've searched on stack overflow but didn't find anything close what i need, so if it's duplicated, tell me and i'll delete this post.

I have a web application that is a single REST service and only does a **Thread.sleep(10000)**. If the method only sleeps for 10 seconds, all my requests should have an average response time 10-11 seconds, right?

To test it on JMeter, normally i use 200 threads and 5 seconds ramp up. When the test starts, my average response time stays on 10 seconds but after 100 requests, it starts to increase until 35-42 seconds.

I was very worried about my implementation so i added a Date on first line of my method and print a log to display when it starts and when it ends. All log information display that requests have a duration of 10 seconds.

```
public Response go(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form){
    Date start = new Date();
    try  {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        logger.info("Time " + sdf.format(start) + " - " + sdf.format(new Date()));
    } catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Error:", e);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
    return Response.ok("OK").build();
}
```

I was wondering why Jmeter increases the response time and my log displays the time that i was expecting. Could be something wrong on Jmeter or i really need to worry about my service?

Thank in advance.

---

Test Plan

[image: Thread Group]

[image: HTTP Request]

[image: BeanShell PreProcessor]

[image: BeanShell PostProcessor]

Comment: Can you show your test plan ? Do you test in GUI mode or NON GUI ? Where is your jmeter located ? On same machine as the application ?

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE I edited the post and added images of my test plan. I'm running JMeter in GUI MODE and jmeter is on my notebook, app is located at amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following:

- You are using GUI Mode
- You have a View Results Tree listener

So what happens is that View Results Tree Listener holds the Results of every sample and used memory keeps growing leading to more and more Garbage Collection then OOM.

You should absolutely read this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Quick fix:

- Use NON GUI
- Use View Results Tree only to output errors or just remove it

Comment: Another point: when i use Neoload, i got the same problem at jmeter :(

Comment: First did you try my answer ? What are the results ?

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering. I'm trying your answer right now but the result still strange. I've pasted the results here (i changed VU to 30, ramp up 3 and iteration = 7 http://pastebin.com/Z4PfLRDU

Comment: In jmeter says that i have some errors but i didn't found any error on log but i found something curious: some requests have a delay of 10 seconds to start after the last one. Do you have any idea why it's happen? 2015-02-22_23:26:38.052 [qtp999661724-38] INFO TranslatorImpl - Finishing

2015-02-22_23:26:46.931 [qtp999661724-12] Starting

Answer (score 0):

Check your **Latency** metric. As per [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Latency.** JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.

So `Elapsed Time` (what JMeter shows you) is `Response Time` + `Latency`

I think that you are experience the situation described in [How to Analyze the Results of a Load Test](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) guide.